# Selecting Multiple Dates Programatically in kevin luck datepicker - JQuery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have three jQuery datepicker of kevin luck. One datepicker is MultiMonth(Namely Display), other two are single Month(Namely From,To) with bind to a texbox. If user select from date and to date then dates range between From and to should select in Display Datepicker.

My Code are :

```
$(function () {
                $(".Display").datePickerMultiMonth(
                    {
                        startDate: '01/01/1996',
                        numMonths: 3,
                        inline: true,
                        selectMultiple: true,
                        renderCallback: function ($td, thisDate, month, year) {

                            }                                
                        }
                    }
                ).bind(
                    'dpMonthChanged',
                    function (event, displayedMonth, displayedYear) {
                        // uncomment if you have firebug and want to confirm this works as expected...
                        //console.log('dpMonthChanged', arguments);
                    }

                ).bind(
                    'dateSelected',
                    function (event, date, $td, status) {
                        // uncomment if you have firebug and want to confirm this works as expected...
                        //console.log('dateSelected', arguments);
                        //alert(event + "," + date + "," + $td + "," + status);

                    }
                );

                $('#getSelected').bind(
                    'click',
                    function (e) {
                        alert($('div.calendar').dpmmGetSelected());
                        return false;
                    }
                );
            });

$(".from").datePicker({
            startDate: '01/01/1996',
            renderCallback: function ($td, thisDate, month, year) {

            }
        });
$(".to").datePicker({
            startDate: '01/01/1996',
            renderCallback: function ($td, thisDate, month, year) {

            }
        });
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the answer,

when user select from and to date, i save the value as date and i recreate the multimonth calendar. In rendercallback function i check the thisdate with my from,to date, if thisdate is in from,to date range then i add 'selected' class to particular td.

it may't be good approach, but it solves my problem.